# Check time intervals

Tags: ios, swift, timer, nstimeinterval

I am writing an app that is supposed to calculate the salary of hourly work in Sweden. Between certain TimeIntervals on certain days there is an addon to the base salary. I start a timer and compare the current time with the start time to get the elapsed time. How can I check how much of the elapsed time that is in a certain time interval (like 18:00-01:00 the following day or  01.00-06.00). So far I've tried with nested if checks but I want the user to be able to change the interval times.

Comment: Do you only need to measure whole hours or minutes as well?

Comment: @DávidPásztor minutes as well

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `endDate` is less than 24hours later than the `startDate`, you can use below function to determine how much time passed between the two dates in hours and minutes.

You can use `Date.timeIntervalSince(_ date:)` to determine the difference in seconds between two `Date` objects, than you can easily convert the difference to a more human readable format specifying the hours/minutes elapsed.

```
func timeElapsed(from startDate:Date,to endDate:Date)->DateComponents{
    let secondsElapsed = Int(endDate.timeIntervalSince(startDate))
    let minutes = (secondsElapsed%3600)/60
    let hours = secondsElapsed/3600
    return DateComponents(hour: hours, minute: minutes)
}
```

Above function works fine when the days/months are different as well.

Some test data:

```
timeElapsed(from: Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(day: 1, hour: 18, minute: 0))!, to: Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(day: 2, hour: 6, minute: 14))!) //hour: 12 minute: 14 isLeapMonth: false 
timeElapsed(from: Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(day: 1, hour: 20, minute: 46))!, to: Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(day: 2, hour: 4, minute: 14))!) //hour: 7 minute: 28 isLeapMonth: false 
timeElapsed(from: Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(month: 1, day: 31, hour: 20, minute: 0))!, to: Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(month: 2, day: 1, hour: 4, minute: 0))!) //hour: 8 minute: 0 isLeapMonth: false
```

You can easily modify the function to return more `DateComponents` if you decide you'll need more in the future. In case the 24hour difference could be bigger between the two dates, that can be tweaked easily as well.